# Set threshold for each key from bucket elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My system log includes 2 fields, ServiceName and ResponseCode (000 - 999), response saves the processing result of service, 000 is successful. I need to count the number of successes and failures of each service and calculate the success rate.

```
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_service": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "group_by_count": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
                  }
                },
                "group_by_success": {
                  "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                      "ResponseCode": "000"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "group_by_count_succ": {
                      "value_count": {
                        "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "success_percent": {
                  "bucket_script": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "numbersucess": "group_by_success>group_by_count_succ",
                      "totalRequests": "group_by_count"
                    },
                    "script": "params.numbersucess / params.totalRequests * 100",
                    "format": "0.00"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Results returned:

```
         "aggregations": {
          "group_by_service": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 1859,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 94338,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "doc_count": 34361,
                "success_percent": {
                  "value_as_string": "100.00",
                  "value": 100
                },
                "group_by_count": {
                  "value": 34361
                },
                "group_by_success": {
                  "doc_count": 34361,
                  "group_by_count_succ": {
                    "value": 34361
                  }
                },
                "key": "AAA"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 20474,
                "success_percent": {
                  "value_as_string": "89.27",
                  "value": 89.26931718276839
                },
                "group_by_count": {
                  "value": 20474
                },
                "group_by_success": {
                  "doc_count": 18277,
                  "group_by_count_succ": {
                    "value": 18277
                  }
                },
                "key": "BBB"
              },
```

I need to set threshold for each key in bucket:

- If key = AAA, success_percent.value must be greater than 80
- If key = BBB, success_percent.value must be greater than 90

...

Keys that do not meet the conditions will be removed from the bucket, so that when I send an alert email I will only receive valid keys, how can I do this?

Comment: can you add mapping and query you have tried

Comment: Dear @jaspreetchahal, I have updated the post, I have calculated the number of successes and the rate of each service, the problem is that the number of services is very large, I need to set a threshold for each service so that only email alerts for services that meet the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access bucket key in bucket_Selector aggregation. So we  cannot place a check based on terms. This problem should be solved at client side  or data should be indexed with pre-calculated success_percent

There is one dirty way of doing it, by using multiple terms aggregation

```
"aggs": {
    "group_by_service_A": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ServiceName.keyword",
        "include":"A"  ---> aggregation for "A" only, can also be replaced by filter
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
          }
        },
        "group_by_success": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "ResponseCode": "000"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_count_succ": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "success_percent": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "numbersucess": "group_by_success>group_by_count_succ",
              "totalRequests": "group_by_count"
            },
            "script": "params.numbersucess / params.totalRequests * 100",
            "format": "0.00"
          }
        },
        "filter_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "percent":"success_percent"
            },
            "script": "if(params.percent > 20) return true;" --> percent for "A"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "group_by_service_B": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ServiceName.keyword",
        "include":"B"---> aggregation for "B" only, can also be replaced by filter
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
          }
        },
        "group_by_success": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "ResponseCode": "000"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_count_succ": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "ServiceName.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "success_percent": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "numbersucess": "group_by_success>group_by_count_succ",
              "totalRequests": "group_by_count"
            },
            "script": "params.numbersucess / params.totalRequests * 100",
            "format": "0.00"
          }
        },
        "filter_bucket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "percent":"success_percent"
            },
            "script": "if(params.percent > 30) return true;" --> percent for "B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```